# How do I get my server HSM working while connected via RDP? (Win 2019)

Tags: smartcard, hsm, windows-server, rdp, pkcs11

The error I get from pkcs11-tool.exe is "No slots."

My server has a hardware security module (Nitrokey HSM 2) that becomes inaccessible once I connect to my server via Windows Remote Desktop.

Note: this is NOT for logging in with smart cards. I use my HSM to decrypt data with its private key.

I use this HSM with the pkcs11-tool.exe recommended by Nitrokey.

It does not matter whether or not I uncheck the box "Smart Cards or Windows Hello for Business". A workaround is to use a different program (AnyDesk) to connect to the server, but that is not a solution because I don't want to rely on a 3rd party remote access app.

What I'm using is the Nitrokey HSM 2 (https://shop.nitrokey.com/shop/product/nk-hsm-2-nitrokey-hsm-2-7).

**FYI.** If you want to use this HSM on a server; it's very slow. Up to 2.5 seconds for just a single 2048-bit RSA private key decryption. That's not cool if a user needs to repeatedly perform this kind of task. It's also really cheap, at less than $150 delivered, so you get the best possible protection for a low price.

Comment: Seems like Windows treats the HSM like a smartcard. Unfortunately it is a known restriction that smartcards connected to the RDP server are not available in an RDP session.

Comment: @Robert It does seem to act that way. No way around that? I couldn't find it, but I find it hard to Google this particular problem. HSM devices aren't very common compared to smart cards and SSL - and that's all that comes up when I search.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow.com mostly without real answer. This one has an answer and a link to a very interesting blog article that contains the info that access to local smartcards is blocked in an RDP session by design: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978119/using-server-usb-smartcard-reader

Comment: @Robert It doesn't help that this topic spans the subject matters of security, programming, and servers. There's no obvious focus for where to discuss these things. About your link: that is indeed the same problem. The solution is unacceptable for me, so I'll either have to inform administrators that they're breaking the application while logged in, or buy a more expensive HSM that doesn't act like a smart card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For now, I use an alternative solution to logging into the server. TeamViewer, AnyDesk, VNC, an IP KVM, or using your server's BMC will circumvent the problem.**

Robert commented to my question and it seems he was right. There's no real solution unless you want to consider hacking your Windows DLLs:

http://lifayk.blogspot.com/2012/07/windows-smart-card-subsystem-and-remote.html

My only options are to implement a different type of HSM that doesn't act like a smart card, or to mitigate the problem by alerting the administrator that they may be breaking the application while logged in via RDP.

Note: I contacted Nitrokey about this and they eventually agreed - it is a hard limitation of Windows. There is no legitimate workaround, if you want the server to use a smart card-based device it will always be overridden by the RDP client as soon as you log in.